# Retrieve photo albums from Facebook using Graph API

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

My head is currently going nuts trying to figure out the most effective way to retrieve the albums from a fan page I own, to an online page. I've seen a code that used FQL and it worked, but it's too slow and apparently it's outdated.

I've browsed around and came across the Graph API concept but it looks a bit hard to understand. By the way I already have an app registered and I also started to search around the Graph Explorer but I can't come to a conclusion.

Are there any tutorials out there?

**EDIT:** I've tried this code:

```
<?php
$album_id = 'myalbumid';
$access_token = 'accesstoken';

$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$album_id}/photos?access_token={$access_token}";
$image = json_decode(file_get_contents($url));

foreach($image->data as $img){
echo "<img src='{$img->images[6]->source}' />    ";

}
?>
```

And it works, it displays all the photos from a given album. But what if I want it to display all albums (including thumbs) and the user navigates through them?

Answer (score 0):

Requesting the following will give you a reply with all albums and photos in those albums:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/CocaCola/albums?fields=photos
```

You'll want to replace `CocaCola` in the example with your own page name or ID.

This is called [nested requests or field expansion](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.1#fiedlexpansion). There are several detailed examples on the Facebook Documentation site.

A few comments for you to help you along the way:

- Calls to retrieve page objects don't need an access token so long as the page does not have age and/or country restrictions. Unless you legally need them, I wouldn't recommend adding restrictions.
- Using `file_get_contents()` is okay for sandbox testing, but you should use the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0) for production code.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've checked the SDK a bit, even downloaded the files and look at the examples. But neither has echoes. How are things displayed and where can I check the codes? For example, my code above was taken from another place, how do they know that's those are the right tags? I think I'm failing to understand how to implement whatever I get from the graph api.

Comment: The SDK is a toolkit to help you get data from Facebook into a PHP variable or object. The current iteration of documentation is rather confusing, especially if you don't understand PHP objects and classes. Spending a little time reading up on those will help.

Comment: For figuring out what tags to use, get acquainted with [print_r()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) and [var_dump()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). Both allow you to inspect the contents of a variable, and use that information to figure out how to iterate over it.

Comment: Can you show me an example of how I can retrieve the albums' imagens and respective name of, for example, the cocacola page? Though the thumbs should have the original size. In FQL I'd do src_big.